# Google Drive files deleted along with *previous* owner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

In our Google workspace for education, an account (A1) was deleted.
Previously, Google drive files' ownership were transferred to another account (A2).
Yet, the deletion of the account A1 implied the deletion of the files previously owned by A1 as well. Thus, A2 wasn't able to access them anymore.
We got to undelete the account A1 in order to be able to access files again.
It is not the way ownership is meant to work AFAICT: is it a bug or an intended feature?
How to overcome this behaviour (the files were linked in a Google Site - whose ownership was also transferred - so downloading the files and uploading again would break the URLs).

Answer (score 1):

This is an expected behaviour stated here:
[Restore a deleted user's Drive files](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2993112?hl=en#:%7E:text=When%20you%20delete%20a%20user,before%20they%27re%20permanently%20deleted.)

> When you delete a user, if you don't transfer files at the time, the
> user's files are deleted 20 days later. If you act quickly, you can
> restore the deleted user and transfer ownership of their files before
> they're permanently deleted.

The files are only not deleted when it is in shared drives, since it is under ownership of the entire team.